# Getting "wrong username or password" after an auth redirect in Android WebView

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a Twitter REST API-Android application.
When user clicks **Sign in with Twitter** I run a `GET authorize/authenticate` and redirect user to `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=aaa123`

- If user is already logged in, Twitter page asks user for authorization. Everything is fine.
- If user isn't logged in, on top of the page this text appears:

  "Something is technically wrong" "wrong username or password"

  And Twitter page asks user to fill username and password. My visitors complains about this warning on top. They say that they even didn't fill their username and password but Twitter page says that wrong password. What creates this alert ? How can I prevent it ? Should I add more parameters in authorize/authenticate ?

After user fills username and password, auth flow finishes successfully. But I need to disable  false error.

(I don't get this error on mobile browsers or desktop browsers. Only in mobile app)

Comment: Are you using some library or trying to authenticate your self via WebView ?

Comment: I use tmhOAuth library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The problem is loading Twitter auth page.

When I use this I get "wrong username or password" error:

```
webView.postUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=aaa123",
        EncodingUtils.getBytes(data, "base64"));
```

I don't get this error for this type of call:

```
webView.loadUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=aaa123");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `Twitter4j` library for the integration of `Twitter` within your `Android Application`. 
Because this Library encapsulates all the Authentication, Tweeting, Fetching Tweets, etc chores within itself. And we have to just call simple methods from this Library for using these features in our Android App.

**Twitter4J features**:
✔ 100% Pure Java - works on any Java Platform version 5 or later
✔ Android platform and Google App Engine ready
✔ Zero dependency : No additional jars required
✔ Built-in OAuth support
✔ Out-of-the-box gzip support
✔ 100% Twitter API 1.1 compatible

You can follow this url for further information related to `Twutter4j` : 
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I'm happy with tmhOAuth and I'm focused on solving this particular problem.

Comment: That's okay, please post the Code that you are using along with the question.